# How do I push the footer to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, footer

I don't have any space under my footer in the desktop as well as the mobile versions with the exception of the iPhone X and the iPad. I've messed around with `media`, `calc(100vh - height)` `overflow`, `position` etc., but nothing seems to be working. I read one suggestion that was to put all the content into a container and then set the footer to `position: absolute`, but I'm not sure how that will affect my grid.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.services-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 3fr;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}

.services-grid {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.services-grid>div {
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 30px;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <section class="services-banner">
    <div class="services-vertical-center">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="services-grid-wrapper">
    <div class="services-grid">
      <div class="services-grid-desc">
      </div>
      <div class="services-grid-desc">
      </div>
      <div class="services-grid-desc">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;/* Footer height */
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;/* Footer height */
}
```

or use a grid:

```
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <header></header>
        <main></main>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'header'
    'main'
    'footer';
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 5rem 1fr 5rem;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```css
    
    html,  div, header, nav, section,
    time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
    }
    
    
    footer,header,nav,section {
    display:block;
    }
    

    .services-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    width: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto 3fr;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    height: calc(100vh - 30px);
    }
    
    
    .services-grid {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .services-grid > div {
    background-color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 30px;
    }
    
    body{
        background-color:rgb(39, 39, 39);
          }
    .footer {
       position: fixed;
       left: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       width: 100%;
       background-color: black;
       color: white;
       text-align: center;
       padding: 17px;
    }
    a{
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 18px;
      color:white;
      text-decoration:none;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="services-banner">
            <div class="services-vertical-center">          
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="services-grid-wrapper">
            <div class="services-grid">
                <div class="services-grid-desc">                  
                </div>
                <div class="services-grid-desc">                 
                </div>
                <div class="services-grid-desc">                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <div class="footer">
        <a href="">Terms
       </a>
       <a href="">Privacy policy</a>
       <a href="">About</a>
       <a href="">Contact Us</a>
    
        </div>
    </body>
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: If you need something else so please share the Screenshot of the output you want.

Comment: Please explain what you have done in your code so that the person reading it may understand.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. it did move the footer down, but now it's locked at the bottom and there's all this excess space above the footer that I can't get rid of.  i would like the footer at the bottom, but only visible after scrolling down to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the body to be `flex`.

Also it helps setting the `html` and `body` to have a min height of the window height.

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, now the footer is at the bottom, but now there's excess space above the footer that i can't get rid of

Comment: can you share screenshot of  the output you are getting and output you want?

Comment: i just posted one, but not sure if it worked @Nishant